# The relation with redis key redisObject and redis value redisObject

Tags: redis

I know no mater redis key or redis value is a redisObject
it is struct like this

```
  typedef struct redisObject {
        unsigned type:4;
        unsigned encoding:4;
        unsigned lru:LRU_BITS; /* lru time (relative to server.lruclock) */
        int refcount;
        void *ptr;
    } robj;
```

the key redisObject.ptr is point to key's value not the value's value

but I want to know how can redis find the value by the key ? there is no ptr to the value's redisObject .

Comment: https://github.com/antirez/redis#serverh

Answer (score 0):

Redis use Hash table mechanism to store the key-value for fast retrieve. The hash table maintains a list of buckets and each bucket has a linked list to store the key-value.

When you add a key to db, it first use hash function to calculate an index. The index tell redis which bucket should accommodate this key. Then redis create an entry for key, add the entry to the head of linked-list which belongs to this bucket and save the value's object ptr, also the key object's ptr to the entry.
The entry is actually an element of the linked list.

So when you want to find the value by key, it use the hash table to achieve this. you could read the **dict.h/dict.c** to learn more about it.

---

**More infos**

**db.c** implement the operation what you want to know.

```
  void setKey(redisDb *db, robj *key, robj *val) {
    if (lookupKeyWrite(db,key) == NULL) {
        dbAdd(db,key,val);
    } else {
        dbOverwrite(db,key,val);
    }
    incrRefCount(val);
    removeExpire(db,key);
    signalModifiedKey(db,key);
  }
```

But it just a wrapper function, and internally use the `dbAdd` or `dbOverwrite` to add the key to db.

And this is the `dbAdd`, it use the `dictAdd` to link the key and val.

```
void dbAdd(redisDb *db, robj *key, robj *val) {
    sds copy = sdsdup(key->ptr);
    int retval = dictAdd(db->dict, copy, val);

    serverAssertWithInfo(NULL,key,retval == DICT_OK);
    if (val->type == OBJ_LIST) signalListAsReady(db, key);
    if (server.cluster_enabled) slotToKeyAdd(key);
 }
```

So the magic thing happens in dict.c, read it!